# C# - SQL Server : Insert query with GETDATE() and Parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, parameters, getdate

UPDATE:

I think the question is:

Why the command replace value of `GETDATE()` by `DATE_CREATED` parameter value although `DATE_CREATED` does NOT EXIST in command query?

I got the problem in `Select` statement as well...

How does `GETDATE()` work?

I'm having a problem with a SQL Server insert query.

I put `GETDATE()` into insert query, but I also put the parameter named `DATE_CREATE` with value `0001/01/01` as well.

And when I execute the insert query, it throw an exception

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Please help me figure out what cause this error.

P/s: Sorry about my bad English

Table create code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USER](
    [USER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [USER_NAME] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [DATE_CREATED] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_USER] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([USER_ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

C# code:

```
    private void Working()
    {
        //Get a SQL Connection
        IDbConnection con = GetConnection();
        USER user = new USER();
        user.USER_ID = 1;
        user.USER_NAME = "User";
        user.DATE_CREATED = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);

        USERDao dao = new USERDao(con);
        con.Open();
        try{
            Insert(con,user);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();
    }

    private int Insert(IDbConnection con,USER obj)
    {
        IDbCommand command;
        command = con.CreateCommand();
        string query = @"INSERT INTO USER (USER_ID, USER_NAME, DATE_CREATED) 
                          VALUES (@USER_ID, @USER_NAME, GETDATE())";
        command.CommandText = query +";";
        addDbDataParameter(command, "USER_ID", obj.USER_ID, DbType.Int32);
        addDbDataParameter(command, "USER_NAME", obj.USER_NAME, DbType.String);
        addDbDataParameter(command, "DATE_CREATED", obj.DATE_CREATED, DbType.DateTime);
        int res = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (res == 0) { throw new Exception("Zero rows were affected."); }
        return res;
    }

    static public void addDbDataParameter(IDbCommand command, string name, object value, DbType dbType)
    {
        IDbDataParameter parameter = command.CreateParameter();
        parameter.DbType = dbType;
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter.ParameterName = "@" + name;
        //parameter.SourceColumn = name;
        if (value == null) { parameter.Value = DBNull.Value; }
        else { parameter.Value = value; }
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
    }
```

As you can see, there is no parameter named `DATE_CREATED` in the insert query (it's `GETDATE()` value), but the command still add the value of `user.DATE_CREATED`.

P/s: I fixed it by removing addParameter `DATE_CREATED` from the command, and it worked.

I hope you can help me learn why it causes the issue... :(

Answer (score 4):

The error message is very explicit about the range of valid dates:

> "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."

The minimum date value for the [`datetime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) data type is `'1753-01-01'`

If you really want to use `'0001-01-01'` then use [`datetime2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) datatype, e.g.:

```
[DATE_CREATED] [datetime2] NOT NULL,
```

If what you really want is the minimum date supported by the SQL Server `datetime` datatype
, then do as `@Damith` suggested and use

```
user.DATE_CREATED = (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue
```

**UPDATE**: (the question is not clear):

`USER`, `USER_ID`, and(!) `USER_NAME`  are all reserved words in SQL Server. Try:

```
    string query = @"INSERT INTO [USER] ([USER_ID], [USER_NAME], DATE_CREATED) 
                     VALUES (@USER_ID, @USER_NAME, GETDATE())";
```

I just created an empty table running your table create statement, and ran this command as TSQL successfully, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO [USER] ([USER_ID], [USER_NAME], DATE_CREATED) VALUES (1, 'joe', GETDATE())
```

Comment: 1+ `datetime2` is the way to go if the OP want range `0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31`

Comment: OP need to know why there is exception even though added parameter not using in the SQL, hope you have good answer for that

Comment: +1 @Damith That's what I'm asking about. SQL replace getdate() in query with value of parameter that not exist?

Comment: @user2780442: I've answered that above.

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL min date is different to c# `DateTime.MinValue` (1/1/0001) , try below,

```
 user.DATE_CREATED = (DateTime)System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue;
```

even though you are not using all the parameters in command parameter collection, it will be a validation for parameter values with the type you given. validation will fail with wrong input.

for example check below

```
var res =new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime(1,1,1); //Invalid SqlDateTime.
```

Comment: I removed the parameter "DATE_CREATED" from command, and it take exactly GETDATE() of DB time.
But can you help me figure out why this problem happen :(

Comment: @user2780442 if you need to insert the time of insert; yes, your approach is correct. no need of parameter. have you check Mitch Wheat's answer? that clearly explain why you get error

Comment: @Damith: Yeah, I checked, it worked. But can you please explain me that the parameter named "DATE_CREATED" is NOT EXIST in the query but why the command still get it value?

Comment: since you adding parameter first of all it should be valid.

Comment: +1 @Damith: I use the method in vary situation, and I want it to be general...
I still don't know why SQL use parameter that doesn't exist in query to replace value of getdate()

Comment: @user2780442 it is not like that, Ok for example, can you give string to datetime parameter in a method call even that method not using that parameter?

Comment: @Damith I'm not clear about your question. Make it simple, I got the problem that SQl query statement always get the value from the input parameter even it's not exist to overload getdate() result. The GETDATE() function I inserted in query has no effect!!

May I send you an email? Or chat? I can explain more clearly what problem I got? I hope you can help. Thanks very much!

My email is: gowithme2005@gmail.com & Skype is go_with_me2005. I'm online now!  ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
 user.DATE_CREATED = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
```

should be

```
 user.DATE_CREATED = DateTime.Now;
```

Why ?

As the error says :

> "SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between **1/1/1753** 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."

But you are setting the date to **0001/01/01** which will thow the error.

Comment: Yeah, but I really want to know why it cause the error.
As you can see, the query doesn't have "DATE_CREATED" parameter?
And I want to use date of Database  ^^